# Why could happen that I can connect to Oracle 10g DB 32 bits but not to 11g DB 64 bits from a 64 bits Forms Server?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, tnsnames

I have just started using WebLogic and the new FORMS and REPORTS Server and builders (11gR2).

I'm using an Oracle 11g R2 64 Bits DB. In the Forms Builder I can open the form an compile it without any problem.

But once I tried to open the form through the browser, it asked me for the DB credentias and then it gave me a TNS Error `ORA-12154`.

Thing is I have double check the `tnsnames.ora` file and everything is alright. So I tried to connect to a 10g DB and it does connect. So it is not a TNSNAMES problem because both DB Address are in the same the tns file.

Question is: What would be the real problem, that is causing this to happen? And how could I solve it?

Tns Entry:

```
    DEV11=
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = dev11)
        )
      )
```

Comment: Can you post your tnsnames.ora file entry?

Comment: Have you double checked sqlnet.ora? Is it using the tnsnames.ora file you double checked?

Comment: Again I really dont think it has to do with the TNSNAMES.ORA file because from the form builder I CAN connect to that DataBase.

Comment: Can you connect to both the databases using `Toad` (or something similar which uses the tnsnames.ora file)?

Comment: @Annjawn Yes I can connect with the SqlDeveloper

Comment: @Laggel... remember that SQLDeveloper does not necessarily need a tnsnames.ora file by default. However, if you want to use it you will have to set the path using the `Tools->Preferences` menu in SQLDeveloper. That was the reason I asked `Toad` and not `SQLDeveloper`.

Comment: I can't connect with toad cuz the db is 64 bit. But again I can connect with the Forms Builder.

Comment: And who exactly said that `Toad` does not work on a 64bit Oracle database? Because you need to check back with your sources again.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the following thread I think your problem is the same:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3455198